# spring integration: Context closes while messages are being processed

Tags: spring-integration

I have a main class that reads records from DB and passes to a spring gateway(Spring integration), from there on I split the messages into a multithreaded application with queues.

My Sping application is closing the context while the messages are still being processed by spring integration adapters.

Need a mechanism to only close the context after all of the messages get processed.

As a temporary workaround, I am using thread.sleep in a while loop to keep the program alive

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest to have a bean like:

```
Semaphore queueSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
```

And `acquire()` it in the beginning of your application. Do the same in the end before closing application context. In this case the second `acquire()` will wait until `release()` somewhere in your application when you realize that all the messages have been just processed.

Another trick is via standard `System.exit(0)` in the point you see that all the messages are processed. But in this case you should not close application context manually.

Comment: Thanks Artem for your prompt reply, but the handling is done using a jdbc adapter, lets say if I pass some 50 messages to a gateway which subsequently passes messages to jdbc adapter, I would not know when all 50 are complete, so I guess the real question is how would I know all of the messages are processed by JDBC adapter

Comment: Well, the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` returns `List` of records. So, you may have some `AtomicInteger` to count down while you are processing messages. And if it is `0`, call `System.exit(0)`